# Appending HTML to Javascript Fireunit Tests

Tags: javascript, unit-testing

I have been meaning to integrate unit testing into my javascript development for some time and because i'm already so used to using firebug to debug and test, fireunit was naturally the obvious choice to do JS unit testing.

I understand how to use fireunit but I am still confused about how to use it both practically and effectively. My main concern is the inability to test any function that actually manipulates the DOM, which lets face it, is almost all of them.

For instance, I might have a function that looks something like this.

```
function() {
    var el = document.getElementById('el');
    if(el) {
        el.parentNode.removeChild(el); //Removes the child from the DOM
    }
}
```

This is a basic example, but using the function requires interacting with the DOM. How do I unit test this when the HTML containing the element is not loaded!?!

I'm not too familar with jsTestDriver, but to my understanding you can append HTML to the unit test using comments (or thats what the code looks like anyways). Is there a way I can do something like this with fireunit tests? Or am I supposed to just clutter my test.html with snippets of code from all over the place and hope they don't conflict. It would be nice to define a small piece of HTML that gets loaded at the beginning of the function, then removes itself when the test function is complete and moves onto the next.

I've got a few ideas such as using innerHTML to load and unload snippets into a testing DIV, but all of my approaches seem unclean and would require a ton of boilerplate be written for each and every testing function. I'd like to hear from a few people who might have already come up with a more efficient solution.

Answer (score 0):

Before the actual execution of the test you could do:

```
var old = document.getElementById;
document.getElementById = function(foo) {
    console.log(foo);
    return {
        parentNode: {
            removeChild: function(bar) {
                console.log(bar);
            }
        }
    };
};
```

Run the test

```
document.getElementById("test"); // console output "test"
```

Reset the original method:

```
document.getElementById = old;
```

I can now not say whether this works cross browser. In my chrome console it was working right now, so I suppose this could work for you. Try it out :)

Another better approach without mocking would be to dynamically create an element containing the DOM that needs to be tested:

```
var container = document.createElement("div");
container.innerHTML = 'your content <span id="el">foobar</span>';
document.body.appendChild(container);
```

run your tests without any mocked objects

afterwards check

```
console.log(document.getElementById("el"), document.getElementById("el").parentNode);
```

clean up of course :)

```
container.parentNode.removeChild(container);
```

I am not into Fireunit so I do not know about asynchronous load possibilities for templates there.